# How to modify regular expression for alphanumeric characters while using capturing groups

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

My regular expression is used to match the email, watzapp, Viber, Line, BBM, snapchat and telephone contacts.

The expression is:-

```
(?i)([\w.]+@[\w.]+)|(?:(?:\b|[,/]\s*)(?:whatsapp|viber|wechat))+\b\s*[:：]?\s*(\+?\d+)|\bline(?:\sid)?\s*(?:[:：]\s*)?(@\w+)|((?:\+\d+)?[ -]?(?:\(\d+\)[ -]?)?[\d -]{6,}\d)
```

The sample strings are:-

```
1) Contact\n♬Line : @PIJ2410J (fast)\n♬BBm : 7470287C\nCustom Case : @KatalogVladdera\nBeauty Care : @Beauty.Vladdera\nTanyakan Stock Dahulu 

2) 8349557\nBhayangkari MOMENT INFINITY\nBISNIS HALAL\n \nINCOME 125rb-14juta /hari\nJoin with myteam fullsuport\n 082120504980\nPin BB :5A878C9D

3) 5-yr online store  Real pictures Mirror Quality 1:1 Whatsapp/Viber +861776345378 spikydudewonderland@gmail.com ✈️✈️Worldwide Shipping

4) Девочки это наша новая страничка.Только копии Lux, искателям дешевых подделок не беспокоить. По всем вопросам viber,whatsapp +79128743333 Лианна

5)Recruitment AgentsThe most powerful manufacturers,we have thebest quality.Wechat:13255996580Whatsapp：+8618820784535

6)  เข้าช้อปทุกวันจ้า ซื้อกับวี้ได้ของแท้แน่นอนค่า แบรนด์อื่นสอบถามได้ค่า ดรีวิว@reviewkayasisshopp LINE ID : @kux1427k (มี @ ด้วยจ้า)
```

As you can see, I have made it into capturing groups. My expression is not able to match the BBM pin which are alphanumeric. How to make the change? Please help.

Here is the link for the regex101 where I tried.https://regex101.com/r/xQ0fM2/5

Comment: The regex looks rather unwieldly. I suggest [appending `\bBBM\s*:\s*(\w+)` to its end](https://regex101.com/r/uD6kX1/1). Or `\w` can be replaced with `[^\W_]` if underscores are not to be grabbed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for your response! Can we make it into another group for BBM? Now in the link which you have posted, its matching the 1st strings's BBM ID but not for the second. How to do that?

Comment: try this one `([\w.]+@[\w.]+)|(?:(?:\b|[,/]\s*)(?:whatsapp|viber|wechat))+\b\s*[:：]?\s*(\+?\d+)|\bline(?:\sid)?\s*(?:[:：]\s*)?(@\w+)|((?:\+\d+)?[ -]?(?:\(\d+\)[ -]?)?[\d -]{6,}\d)|\bBBM?\s*:\s*(\w+)`, I just put a ? after M char on BBM in  Wiktor Stribiżew suggestion...

Comment: Is `BB` = `BBM`? Sorry, the data you have is rather unclear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Actually these strings are the Json responses from the instagram API. People write in different ways (Pin BB, BBM pin ect). I just wanted to capture the alphanumerics which is absolutely correct as you showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex can be enhanced to match the codes you need by [appending `\bBBM\s*:\s*(\w+)` to its end](https://regex101.com/r/rZ3xM5/1).

Note that `\w` can match underscores, so, `\w` can be replaced with `[^\W_]` if underscores should be excluded.

Also, I think the optional `(?:\+\d+)?[ -]?(?:\(\d+\)[ -]?)?` is not necessary at all, it only hampers performance and can be removed.

Try just

```
([\w.]+@[\w.]+)
|
(?:(?:\b|[,/]\s*)(?:whatsapp|viber|wechat))+\b\s*[:：]?\s*(\+?\d+)
|
\bline(?:\sid)?\s*(?:[:：]\s*)?(@\w+)
|
([\d -]{6,}\d)
|
\bBBM?\s*:\s*(\w+)
```

or one line:

```
([\w.]+@[\w.]+)|(?:(?:\b|[,/]\s*)(?:whatsapp|viber|wechat))+\b\s*[:：]?\s*(\+?\d+)|\bline(?:\sid)?\s*(?:[:：]\s*)?(@\w+)|([\d -]{6,}\d)|\bBBM?\s*:\s*(\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uD6kX1/3)

The `[\d -]{6,}\d` part can also be improved, but there is too little data to test.

Comment: Thank you! As you said, there is too little data to test, I've updated in my question. So can test with that too and give your suggestions.

Comment: It seems that all branches start with a word boundary and that creates a big overhead. Try just [`\b(?:([\w.]+@[\w.]+)|(?:(?:\b|[,/]\s*)(?:whatsapp|viber|wechat))+\b\s*[:：]?\s*(\+?\d+)|line(?:\sid)?\s*(?:[:：]\s*)?(@\w+)|([\d -]{6,}\d)|BBM?\s*:\s*(\w+))`](https://regex101.com/r/uD6kX1/5).